# Should I Accept answer for discussion/opinion based question?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I recently asked about [UFW behind a Firewall](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247090/is-ufw-behind-a-firewalled-gateway-router-necessary) & I think I kind of meant for it to be ongoing/discussion based as there is no "correct answer" IMO. Should I just let users answer/upvote the answer they think is best? Should I select an answer I like best?

Comment: i dont know if an *ongoing/dicussion based* question is really suitable here in the first place...

Comment: I mean technically all questions are ongoing/discussion based are they not :P

Comment: No. If they are, they are closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a question for which there can be no single right — or at least, judged to be best — answer, it's not a good fit for Stack Exchange in the first place.

That doesn't mean it's *bad* — it's just not what we're here for. See the site help for more, under [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: this is the right answer.

Comment: Would you say that the question i linked falls under that category?

Comment: I originally asked it in Meta, because it felt off for the main site, but I now understand meta is for asking questions about the site, like this one. (its a learning curve)